# How can I make a line break in a google docs button?

Tags: javascript, button, google-docs, google-docs-api

Hey guys I'm doing my first google docs tables project and I use the following code to create a button:

```
function make_button() {
  var text = text_1 + text_2;
  Browser.msgBox("Button", text , Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

How can I make a line break between this to strings such that later in the button text_2 will appear in a new line?

Tanks a lot!

Greetings 
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line break like this:

```js
var text = text_1 + "\\n" + text_2;
```